# Command button not re-enabling after condition not met automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

I have created a Command button and written a small code using if condition to match my criteria. Its working fine if their is any value in the cell/range, its doing according to code "asking to enter the data" and if their is any value "saying data is already enter" and disabling the button(what exactly i wanted).

But, when i am re-entering the data/value into those cell, it's not re-enabling the button back automatically. I have to manually have to go to properties to enable it, which i don't want to do everytime.

Below is my code"

```
Private Sub RESET_Click()
If Range("A10").Value = "" Then
  Reset.Enabled = False
  MsgBox "Data has already updated for this period"
Else
  Reset.Enabled = True
  MsgBox "Please, enter the data"
End If
End Sub
```

It's not re-enabling the button even after i have listed True in else condition.

Please, also let me know if their is way. So, i can reset/re-enable this button on 1st of every month automatically using VBA.

I would appreciate your response.

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually calling this sub when you want to reset ? It's not listening to an event, so it won't be called unless you call it.

Comment: What you mean, i am using this SUB to just enter a data every monht, if the cell is empty then it should automatically disable the button (so the user can enter the data for that month in those emtpy cells and save it). When the cells have data, this button should be enabled. So, i can attach few other macros in same condition, so it can run and clear the cells and become disable. So, the user can then enter his data whenever he comes in.

Comment: Even, if there is a alternate way as well. So, this button will be disabled after once clicked, so no one can run it again. So, it can be re-enabled on 1st of every month. But, i think the above condition is better as long as the cell is empty, it should be disable. But, appreciate, if someone can attach even this code, so i can adopt alternate option, if needed.

Comment: @rockstar Is `Reset` the name of your button? Is it an ActiveX command button? You might need to explicitly refer to your sheet (`Sheets("Sheet1").Reset.Enabled = False`), etc. Also you should explicitly refer to your critieria range as well, `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10").Value = ""`.

Comment: @rockstar Also it looks like your button's name is `RESET`, but you refer to it as `Reset` in your code. I believe it is case sensitive.

Comment: Hi @dwirony, Yes, my button name is reset and i am using the correct name in my code, just was an error while posting this question. So, as far as on the button name is good. And, on referring to sheet as you mentioned, even i tried that earlier and now seeing your example. Still the issue exists, its not enabling the button once it's executed even after their is data in the cells.

Comment: As @Jean Rostan mentioned in the above, that i have to call it. I tried using different call options but its not enabling. I would appreciate, if you can post code how to call.

Comment: You can do different things, your problem is not fleshed out enough tho. To call a sub, you need to write `Call nameofyoursub Argument1,Argument2,...` making sure it's visible (`private`,module or `public` scope). To call it, you have different choices, you could call it every 1st of the month, using the event workbook opening (which means your code would run when the wb is opened), thanks to `if` statements and `date`. You can also have a button to call this macro, this button would always be on, but it would enable this reset button, only if conditions are satisfied,etc. Not enough details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is triggered by the button press. This way, once the first condition of the `if` statement is met, the button is disabled and won't run its code anymore.

Maybe what you want is to re-eanable the button when cell changing. So put this code on the worksheet after setting your sub to public:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A10")) Is Nothing Then call RESET_click
End Sub
```

EDIT:

Maybe you also have to `set` the button object inside your main `sub`:

```
Set Reset = yourworksheet.Buttons("yourbuttonname")
```

I would also recomend not to use `Reset` as name inside VBA, since it is already a statement, and may cause confusion.

Comment: i have changed my code to public sub and add the private sub under the sheet but it's not working, it's throwing an error every time, it reach the enabling button code line "Reset.enabled= True". It's throwing "object required (#424)" error everytime.

Comment: @Jean, i not trying to call the sub inside my sub but i am trying to enable the command button.

Comment: Clear expanation:                                                                                               I was able to run my above code to successfully check the condition and disable the command button, if their the range of cells range("C5"C8") is  empty. But, i couldn't able to Re-enable the command button back using the "button.enabled = True" option (throwing "object required #424" error). So, i need a code to enable the command button, if the values in the cells is changed??

Comment: Maybe if you set the button object?